# Parsing SVG with Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse svg via simple html dom.

Managed to get svg as html element from original page:

```
<svg class="EndorsementIcon-background">
    <use xlink:href="https://static.playoverwatch.com/svg/icons/circle-d9d589e7b6.svg#circle"></use>
</svg>
```

As I understand Simple HTML Dom can not get xml which is inside svg. Can I parse svg element using php?

Used html simple dom code to find div by class name:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/simple_html_dom.php';
$data = file_get_html('http://playoverwatch.com/player-profile');
$result = $data->find('.endorsement-level',0);
echo $result;
```

Parsed SVG element on my html page should look like this:

```
<svg class="EndorsementIcon-background" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="15.9155"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is not so much about “parsing” per se, but about the fact that this SVG references an external entity. You need to make an HTTP request to get the contents of `https://static.playoverwatch.com/svg/icons/circle-d9d589e7b6.svg` yourself at this point.